# Run a code if a range contains a date in a given period

Tags: vba, date, if-statement

I want to come up with a code that checks if B:B contains dates between 1/1/2015 and 12/31/2015. If the criteria is met then I want the code to run the following code:

```
Range("m2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS(I:I,B:B,"">=""&DATE(2015,1,1),B:B,""<=""&DATE(2015,12,31),G:G,""=FALSE"")"
```

And if the criteria is not met the I need no further actions to be taken. I also need to refer to the period in a way that will enable the code to work with all date&region formats.

Any help on the matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the work:

```
Sub CheckDate()

Dim MyRange As Range: Set MyRange = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
Dim DateCell As Range

    For Each DateCell In MyRange

        If Year(DateCell) = 2015 Then

            DateCell.Offset(0, 11).Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS(I:I,B:B,"">=""&DATE(2015,1,1),B:B,""<=""&DATE(2015,12,31),G:G,""=FALSE"")"

        End If

    Next DateCell

End Sub
```

I set `MyRange` from B1 to the last non empty row, then I do do a `For Each` loop through it and check if the year of the date is equal to 2015, if it is I apply your formula using `.Offset(0, 11)` which stay on the same row (0) and move 11 columns to the right (11) so to column M in the same row.